# Issue in importing gen package

Tags: go

I am trying to import gen package in main.go file.

```
import ("golang.org/x/text/internal/gen")
```

But I am facing following error and still I haven't find solution to this:

```
main.go:7:2: use of internal package golang.org/x/text/internal/gen not allowed
```

Could someone help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: That's by design, you are not allowed to import someone else's `internal` packages. See: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Internal_Directories

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva for the reply. Is there any way to use internal packages?

Comment: No, importing someone else's `internal` package will cause the build to fail. If you want to use the code from an internal package, you need to copy it from the source into your own package and then import your own package. This way it won't be someone else's internal anymore.

Comment: @mkopriva I tried but get an error `main.go:5:2: code in directory /home/pc13/go/src/practice/gen expects import "golang.org/x/text/internal/gen"`

Comment: Remove the comment after the `package` clause in the `gen.go` file ([this one](https://github.com/golang/text/blob/master/internal/gen/gen.go#L19)). Also, if you haven't yet, create a go module so that you can easily import the package. It works for me: https://imgur.com/4KGHPUl

Comment: Actually, if you have a go module you don't have to remove the comment. With Go modules import-checking is disabled. See [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Import_path_checking), it says: *"Import path checking is also disabled when using modules. Import path comments are obsoleted by the go.mod file's module statement."*